# Jquery $.ajax returns internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am sure i am doing something bad here, but i cannot figure out what.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("li").bind("click", function () {
                var sel = $(this).attr('id').toString();
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: sel,
                    url: "Default.aspx/SaveValue",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any advises please?
And here is the debug info gathered[image]

**UPDATE:** By changing to `data: "{var1:'test'}",` and `dataType: "json",` everything works as expected

Comment: I hope if you got a 500 response from the server it was not because anything was wrong with your client jQuery code!  A 500 error *is supposed to mean* the fault is at the server.  If that server predictably gives a 500 due to a request then it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RayToal nope! i do not get a 500 error. And The web method SaveValue is not called at all

Comment: If you don't get a 500 error, then why is _internal server error_ in the title?  FYI: "internal server error" => 500

Comment: @Sparky I meant i do not get a server side 500 error. The webpage continues to operate normally. The error is raised client side... I guess :)

Comment: Again, a "500 error" **IS** an "internal server error"... same thing.  By definition, it's impossible to get a server error on client-side.  My guess is that `Default.aspx/SaveValue` is the cause... can you load that URL in your browser?

Comment: What is the actual response you got from the server?  We see that `debugger` was called.  Can you alert or log the server response?  Or use Poster or curl from the commandline when doing that POST?

Comment: @RayToal, it's shown in his screenshot... second line.

Comment: I thought there would be something in the actual HTTP response (a body, perhaps) that wasn't shown in the debugger output.  Maybe `936_2` is all we get.

Comment: If you've solved this, please post your solution as an answer or delete the whole thing.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky Actually this is the value of the id. Could you please check the update?

Comment: I see that, but I still maintain that if you have a malformed HTTP request, say your `Content-Type` header was messed up or you data was not properly formatted, or whatever, that any properly functioning server should reply to you with a 415, 400, or 406, and **not** a 500.  That's all I was saying.  Glad you found your solution!

Comment: @RayToal makes a great point.  Don't ignore this or be misled into thinking your client-side JS was the cause.

Comment: I already saw your update and that's why I asked you to post your solution as an answer below.  If it's still not solved, then clarify as such in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing to `data: "{var1:'test'}",` and `dataType: "json",` everything worked as expected.
Special thanks to Sparky and to all commenters of course